# Block country by geoip with nginx ingress controller and modsecurity

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, mod-security

I'm trying to block one country on nginx ingress controller with modsecurity enabled but still no luck. My configuration is:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/modsecurity-snippet: |
      SecRuleEngine On                                       
      SeqRequestBodyAccess On                                
      SecAuditEngine On                                      
      SecAuditLogParts ABIJDEFHZ                             
      SecAuditLog /var/log/modsec_audit.log                  
      SecGeoLookupDb /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoIP.dat
      SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,id:22,drop,msg:WrongIP"
      SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "@streq GR"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 0.0.0.0/0
```

when I try to access URL with curl I'm getting HTTP 200 instead of HTTP 403.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: I use kubernetes 1.21 EKS based and nginx-ingress-controller 1.0.3

Comment: Sorry for long time to response. Could you please provide your logs?

Answer (score 0):

Start by validating that your solution works at all:

Try changing your condition from:

`"@streq GR"`

to:

`"!@streq GR"`

and testing again. If your rules are actually working then the result you get should flip: 200 to 403 or 403 to 200.

Comment: already tried that: allow only one country. but when I try to access host with: curl -H "User-Agent: Nikto" https:..... I got 403 so modsecurity is active

Comment: So `"@streq GR"` gives you a 200 response and `"!@streq GR"` gives you a 403 response? That sounds like there's a problem either with the lookup or the true source IP address being passed through correctly. What do the audit logs show?

Comment: no. both cases: HTTP200.

Comment: Ah, understood. If both "is GR" and "is not GR" don't work then something is fundamentally broken. What does /var/log/modsec_audit.log say?

Comment: That's strange. With logs configured in a way described above I can't see my requests in the logs. I'm trying to access curl https://...../info but in the logs I see only requests to /nginx_status and /is-dynamic-lb-initialized